# Hosted Job Scheduler ( Quartz Scheduler as a service )

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is there any product that will allow us to schedule via an api , and then if the time is triggered then it should call the destination via webhook(with payload preferably )

Right now we are using quartz scheduler which has more configuration (Including Mysql Connection ) .
Cons are 1) Does not have an admin UI 2) No reporting or history of jobs

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

You may try Citrine, which is a web gui around Quartz, and easily customizable.